# Can I install julia on anaconda without creating new environment?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, anaconda, julia, conda

I am an Ubuntu user, I have anaconda py3, I want to install `julia` form `conda-forge` channel, but when installing it using the following

```
conda indstall -c conda-forge julia
```

It tells me that some of the packages are gonna upgraded, I am afraid that it may cause a conflict with py3.

I know I can create an environment for `julia` using

```
conda create -n julia -c conda-forge julia
```

but I want to know I there is any one know what it will cost to not create a separate environment for `julia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I can, but firstly I need to add `conda-forge` to channels

```
conda config --append conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority true

conda install julia
```

In this way I don't have to create a new environment, or cause any conflict between the default channel and conda-forge channel